Movie where a man tells his lifestory about how his daughter is not actually his own
I had watched this movie in like 2007 and forgot the name. It's a movie where I think there were 2 or 3 friends meet and one of them tells his story about how his beloved wife had cheated on him and gave birth to their daughter who is not actually his but of his friend's (I think)
He had never told anyone about the fact that he actually knows she is not his own daughter yet she means the world to him. 

Chaos Theory?

Good god ! That's the movie.. Thanks man

u r welcome! I'll post it as an answer now

Chaos Theory 2008
From IMDB

At his daughter's wedding, time-management specialist Frank Allen corners the reluctant groom and tells him a long story: about the night his wife chose him, and then, about eight years later, when a missed ferry, a corporate groupie, a panicked expectant mother, and a medical test brought Frank's marriage to a crisis. In the midst of the crisis were Frank, his wife Susan, their daughter Jesse, and Frank's best friend, the feckless Buddy. Things come to a head at a lake when Frank, armed with a shotgun, decides to cross something permanently from one of his time-management lists. Is there ever room for whim and chaos?




